# Batch file to find duplicate folder (different levels) names and exports list

Tags: windows, batch-file, indexing, directory

I have found on this site the batch script to list all folder names in a text file. My question is what can I add to the script to get a list of the subfolders names (mainly just 2nd level) Im going through about 10 1 and 2TB external hdds looking for duplicate folder names (not trying to delete them yet) any ideas? Also can I add multiple paths so that the batch can be run on the desktop and check all hdd's without copying&pasting to every level 1 folder?. This is the script I have right now.

```
@echo ON
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%# in (*.*) do (
echo "%%~n#">>text.txt
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well sub-folders are easy, simply use `/r`:

```
@echo ON
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R /D %%# in (*) do (
    echo "%%~n#">>text.txt
)
```

To only search upto the second level for sub-folders:

```
@echo ON
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%# in (*) do (
    echo "%%~n#">>text.txt
    pushd %%#
    for /D %%A in (*) do (
        Echo "%%~nA">>..\text.txt
    )
    popd
)
```

As for multiple hard-drives, if you only have 2 or 3 I don't see whats wrong with copying and pasting.

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks! How is it possible to know what the level of the folder is? Can a the batch file show that? Or am I asking to much from it?

Comment: When I search for second level folders when there are more than one 1st level folder it seems to only show the 1st folders second levels and not the rest. Other than that its good.